# Notepad ++ and regex finding second character and move it to new line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am not familiar with regex, I'm using Notepad++ to try and clean some data I received. Is there a way to find a second appearance of a character and place it on a new line?

E.g

```
1|name|surname|address|1|name|surname|address
```

I need to find the second appearance of the number '1' and put it on to a new line.

```
1|name|surname|address
1|name|surname|address
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Will the number always be `1`? Or is it different for different records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\|(?=1\|)`
- Replace with: `\n`    or `\r\n` depends on platform
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\|      : a pipe, must be escaped because it has special meaning in regex
(?=     : start lookahead, a zero length assertion to be sure we have after
  1     :   the digit 1
  \|    :   a pipe
)       : end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n      : linebreak for linux files
```

or

```
\r\n    : linebreak for windows
```

- *check Wrap around*
- *Check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Result for given example:**

```
1|name|surname|address
1|name|surname|address
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, it worked fine. but i am experiencing a different problem with another file lol. but i will post another question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the Replace dialog :

- Find what : `^(1[^1]*)\|1(.*)$`
- Replace with : `\1\n1\2`

Explanation:

Search from the beginning of the line
for `1` followed by any number of `not-1`, followed by `|1`,
followed by any character until the end of the line.

Replace by the text that matched the inside of the first parenthesis,
followed by new-line and `1` and then
the text that matched the inside of the second parenthesis.

Don't forget to ensure that "Regular expression" is checked in "Search mode".

Comment: You may need \r\n for the Windows CR/LF convention.